# Reconfigure keyboard permanently

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I write in Polish. In the Polish default keyboard on the special Polish characters are created by pressing right alt and several letters (z,s,c etc). Since I work a lot on macs I am used to another combination LEFT ALT + the letter. On my laptop I prefer the combination window key + the letter. In any case I find it difficult to type fast using the default combination of left alt + letter. In Freya it was easy to fix this by choosing 3rd level, in Loki it became impossible. To solve the problem I use command "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration" and choose the combination I need BUT I HAVE TO DO IT EVERY TIME I RESET THE COMPUTER OR START WORKING. It is maybe acceptable but quite annoying. Is there any way I could preserve the keyboard layout I reach after using the reconfigure series of options (this takes some time and becomes tedious)? I would be grateful if hopefully someone told me how they reconfigured the keyboard permanently, many thanks Marek, Poland

Answer (score 1):

After changing your keyboard settings, do in terminal:

```
setxkbmap -query
```

You should see the options you have chosen,e.g:

```
    setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de
variant:    mac
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

You can try setting this command:

```
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout pl -option 'lv3:lwin_switch'
```

with your options. I'm not sure if this is going to be permanent, try it out.

If it's not permanent, there are 2 options:

1. changing /etc/default/keyboard:

in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

A text-file will be opened where you can write your input. This should be loaded upon startup.

2. putting your command in Startup-Aplications:

Go to System-Settings->Applications and add a new Startup-Apllication with your command above, eg:

```
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout pl -option 'lv3:lwin_switch'
```

**EDIT:**
you can see all the possible layouts and options in this file: /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst

Comment: Many thanks I shall try it out today. Most grateful ;)

Comment: No luck so far. This is my options: 
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     pl
options:    lv3:lwin_switch

Comment: How do I use this info? There is no way to load the lv3 stuff and in every method I end up with the same problem - special characters on right alt while I would prefer them on the left alt like it is done in a mac keyboard. Please give me a hint.

Comment: I tried the nano command but cannot save the file, anyway I do not know how to implement lv3:lwin_switch, with -options it is treated as an error

Comment: @Marek Try:  
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout pl -option 'lv3:lwin_switch'     
For the other approach: just put lv3:lwin_switch after options in the text file. You save the file with Ctrl+O and exit with Ctrl+X. (Be sure to run **sudo** nano /etc/default/keyboard )

Comment: Many thanks :) the start up method with the commond you kindly supplied worked superbly, now I have my special characters on the left. Another happy elementary user. Best Marek

Comment: @Marek I'm glad it helped! don't forget to mark the answer as correct so the question is set as "answered"

Comment: Eric many thanks, one thing, after I turn on the computer it does not work - to activate the keyboard layout I need to restart the machine. Strange. I will mark it as you suggest. Many thanks.

Comment: startup applications should be executed on restart and on normal boot, you can try to add an delay to the command (within your startup application):  sleep 3 && setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout pl -option 'lv3:lwin_switch'

Comment: Many thanks, sorry to bother you but the command does not work - I mean I have to reboot the computer. When I switch it on, normal boot the result is the machine using the default polish keyboard, right alt combinations for special characters. I copied the command carefully and made it active. Maybe my computer HP DV6-3000 is strange :) But I can live with one reboot to get what I want - the disk is SSD and it if rather fast :) Many thanks

Comment: So to clarify: if you use the command directly in terminal or if you reboot it works as you want but for normal startup not?

Comment: I used the command you kindly suggested in start up option and it did not work when booting the device from zero. So I deleted it and inserted the original command you had given before - I just started it, booted from zero and dadam! I have the right keyboard. So it means something is wrong with my hardware maybe rather than with the commands. Anyway I will keep on using it and checking if the problem has been solved somehow. Please tell me where I could mark it as solved which I hope it is. Cheers Marek

Comment: Started it again from zero and the machine works using the reconfigured keyboard. Many thanks :) how this happened I do not know. Will anyone tell me that computers do not have souls of their own?

Comment: Ha ha, incredible. Started it again from zero and got wrong layout BUT WHEN switched off and started again the command works (the same command as I changed nothing there). Very strange, hope you understand this :)

Comment: Maybe the waiting was too short and sometimes the machine isn't "ready" when executing the command.  Try "sleep 5 && ...." Or any higher number (it's the time it's waiting in seconds)

Comment: Many thanks for help. Most grateful. The original command without sleep started suddenly working on boot - for no apparent reason. There is one more thing on the reconfiguration. I wonder if it is possible to swap left control with left alt. There may be an option to do this but I find it difficult to google this.

Comment: Open /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst for all the possible options. There are a lot ;)

Comment: Again, many thanks - I solved it myself owing to your suggestion - both changes to configuration work now. So simple when you know what to do :)

Comment: Glad to hear you are happy now!

Comment: One step to total happiness is ability to sort out icons of files "by hand", move them around the window :) There is choice: by date, by type etc. but pushing files around when I work - read stuff, collect info, is crucial. I asked another question on this - maybe Elementary allows for this some linux disrtbutions do but they look ugly (mostly) :) Many thanks Eric

Comment: Hi Marek: as this question will pop up to the community again and again if it's not fixed, please accept the answer, as it's actually solved.

Comment: "as this question will pop up to the community again and again if it's not fixed" ...yeah like now... xD (3 months later)

Comment: Actually 1 year and 3 months later ;)